# java -cp h2*.jar org.h2.tools.Backup -? no work

Tags: java, windows, h2

I have Windows 7 and try to execute 
java -cp h2*.jar org.h2.tools.Backup -?
 In prompt i see that file with jar extenson is not find. How solve this problem. I aldhougt write all path (C/Program Files/H2 ... etc.).

Answer (score 1):

That's not the syntax for classpath wildcards. You need either to list each JAR separated by (semi)colons or use `[directory/]*` to sweep up all the JARs in the directory. You can't use wildcards to cherry-pick specific file patterns. All this would have been clear to you had you Read the Fine Manual at 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/classpath.html#A1100762 
and related pages.